cordova-plugin-shell wrong command JavaScript
I need to emulate screen taping im my capacitor app. I can use cordova-plugin-shell, it works fine, but only as in example :
window.ShellExec.exec('uptime', function(res){console.log('exit status: ' + res.exitStatus)console.log('cmd output: ' + res.output)})

If I try to use other commands, I receive exit status 100 (wrong command).
I need to use this function:
window.ShellExec.exec('input tap 500 500', function(res){console.log('exit status: ' + res.exitStatus)console.log('cmd output: ' + res.output)})


it works on PC, no root required, but not works from my app, may be problem is in whitespaces in adb command?

Please tag your question with the programming language used. Is this Javascript?

yes, Javascript

You should probably try as root user then
 window.ShellExec.exec(['su', '-c', 'input tap 500 500'], function(res){
      console.log('exit status: ' + res.exitStatus)
      console.log('cmd output: ' + res.output)
 })


I get: exit status: 100
script.js?a=125:777 cmd output: org.json.JSONArray cannot be cast to java.lang.String

I think the version on NPM does not include this patch https://github.com/petervojtek/cordova-plugin-shell-exec/commit/a65823d11ac8f9d577ef417040f61af12339d924 so you should clone / install from github instead of using NPM

I had replaced the plugin files with files from github, but the result is the same. Maybe this function is only for root devices?

Did you remove the previous plugin and installed the plugin from github from cordova?

it works, thank you.
